# Can I use Leap Motion controller as a touchscreen replacement?

Tags: leap-motion

I bought a Leap Motion Controller because I would develop a software for my rehabilitation. Can I use the leap motion controller to do something like: I indicate a point on the screen and the leap motion controller recognize exactly which point I indicate?

Naturally I don't speak about an indication from some meters or with some inclination, I speak about something like a replacement of a touch screen.

Well, as @this. __curious_geek asked I will try to describe a test that now I do and what I would do.

Now I must touch a screen where I see a white square on a black background, this square change its position when I touch the screen ok?

Now I would develop a software that do the same thing but using the leap motion. Is it possible?

I just find this application:

https://airspace.leapmotion.com/apps/touchless-for-windows

but it hasn't the precision that I'm looking for!

Comment: There are a fair number of applications that let you control OS by pointing at the screen. There are limitations, but you could use it as a replacement, more-or-less. And if you want to implement it yourself, it's pretty easy. I could show you a sample in C# if you want.

Comment: @nphx Thank you very much for your reply! Which are the limitations?

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to provide a concrete answer since this is a subjective discussion. You can try identifying actual use-cases for end-users and then work your way up to the decision by case-to-case comparison. Leap Motion is very cheap compared to the touch-screen options available in the market. I would rather buy one Leap Motion Controller myself to validate use-cases and check if Leap Motion stands the test. The cost is hardly 100 USD so it is rather more affordable to buy one and test on the real device. If it works out, you're good to go or else you will end up with a list of use-cases that didn't work with the Leap Motion and you can start working on figuring out alternates.

Comment: thank you for your answer! Now I will try to describe an example!

Answer (score 0):

The Leap Motion device field of view is an inverted pyramid about 2 feet high. If your monitor  is larger than this space, then you won't be able to reach every point on the monitor.

Another challenge is that the device has no knowledge of the position of the screen, so you would have to create a calibration procedure for correlating the physical position of the screen to Leap Motion coordinates.

Finally, the way that the hand/finger recognition works causes the finger to stop being recognized when it actually touches the monitor surface (it no longer looks like a finger). This limitation should be removed in an upcoming SDK release.